# JSF and Glassfish - settings and where to put files in doc root

Tags: netbeans, glassfish

I am really confused, because I find a lot of information to special stuff around glassfish, but not this basics. I made a test JSF project with primefaces in Netbeans on computer1. When compiled, it runs on the glassfish 4 server, started by Netbeans. I also set up a Glassfish 4 Server on my Linux box computer2 - it is running and working. Now I wanted to transfer this Netbeans project from computer1 and run it on computer2.

I think what I need are the files in build/web in the Netbeans project. But when I put them into a subfolder "web" of my doc root on computer2, the first difference is:

- When I call `http://DOMAIN/web`, I get a "404".
- When I call `http://DOMAIN/web/index.xhtml` directly, it is shown in the browser, but not interpreted.

So my question: What have I to do so that this project runs on computer 2 like when compiled and run with Netbeans? And: Where is the best place to find such basal information?

Thanks
WoTim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't simply copy the uncompiled project folder to an application container. NetBeans support generating a WAR file (located in the dist folder of your project by default). Then use the web-interface or asadmin to deploy the WAR. The root of your NetBeans project will be accessible from `http://DOMAIN/CONTEXT/`